# Unabled connect minikube dashboard

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kvm, ubuntu-server, minikube

I configured my Ubuntu server (192.168.1.6) with minikube and kvm2, all seems ok

```
 $ minikube start --vm-driver=kvm2 Starting local
 Kubernetes v1.8.0 cluster... Starting VM... Getting VM IP address...
 Moving files into cluster... Setting up certs... Connecting to
 cluster... Setting up kubeconfig... Starting cluster components...
 Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster. Loading cached images
 from config file.


$ kubectl get po --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       node-hello-6dd6c8bb-j672z               1/1       Running   3          1d
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube             1/1       Running   4          3d
kube-system   kube-dns-86f6f55dd5-27ttl               3/3       Running   12         3d
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-77c67f7cd9-wxsg9   1/1       Running   4          3d
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-n2fd4              1/1       Running   4          3d
kube-system   storage-provisioner

$ minikube dashboard --url
http://192.168.39.172:30000
```

But I cant't access on this IP from my home network on my computer (192.168.1.10).

When I put `telnet 192.168.39.172 30000` I got error IP not reachable.

**EDIT** :

I think I need to use **SSH port forwarding**

```
kubectl proxy &
ssh -R 30000:127.0.0.1:8001 docker@192.168.39.172
```

but I can't open the port 30000 because it already listen in the Ubuntu server

`tcp 0 0 :::30000 :::* LISTEN`

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
But I cant't access on this IP from my home network.
```

If I understand correctly, that you try to access minikube started on one computer from another one in your local network, then it will not work. At least not until the client knows how to route traffic so that it can reach 192.168.39.172 which is a local bridge interface for your minikube VM.

One of the solutions could be to set up additional routing rule to point 192.168.39.0/24 to the IP of your minikube host.

Another would be to run `kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0` on minikube host so that api is exposed on all interfaces (please mind that kubectl proxy adds authorization on it's own, meaning that if you open it like this, anything can access the API as you, without any auth)

Comment: "One of the solutions could be to set up additional routing rule to point 192.168.39.0/24 to the IP of your minikube host." => how can I do this ? thx

Comment: On the PC you want to connect from run something like `ip ro add 192.168.39.0/24 via <ip_of_minikube_host>`

Comment: I'm under Windows and I tried to add additional routing rule on my wireless card without success. I tried also `kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0` but I can't access to http://192.168.39.172:30000/ui/

Comment: Or it's not possible to change minikube IP to match on my local network (192.168.1.x) ?

Comment: Nope, not really. Kubernetes needs a subnet for pods, it can't really deploy pods inside your nodes network. Please mind that minikube is intended for local development. For something more "public" you might want to look in `kubeadm` direction.

Comment: Thx @Radek, I used minikube to my personnal development on my server. I want to have several docker to have multiple tools in order to do some POC

Comment: I tried to do `ip ro add 192.168.39.0/24 via 192.168.39.172` but I obtain `RTNETLINK answers : Network is unreachable`

Comment: I tried SSH port forwarding with `ssh -R 30000:127.0.0.1:8001 $USER@192.168.39.172` on my server but the user is not known on 192.168.39.172. How can I do that ?

Comment: Ok so I tried with docker user without success ! The port is already listen `tcp        0      0 :::30000                :::*                    LISTEN`, how force to do remote port forwarding ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, then I did curl on the dashboard url:

***curl <>:30000/***

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   990  100   990    0     0   966k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  966k            
      **You are using an outdated</strong> browser.
      Please upgrade your browser</a> to improve your
      experience.</p>**

I tried to open the same url from google chrome and was able to see the dashboard.

Sorry if the answer is not helpful, shared what I experienced.